# Можно ли поставить два локальных сервера?

Tags: сервер, denwer

К примеру поверх Денвера возможно еще поставить OpenServer?

Update: Ивините, что долго не писал. Вопрос был вот чем: я начинал с денвера и осталось много тестовых сайтов с денверскими настройками, но в последнее время денвер стал сильно напрягать, и по отзывам вроде OpenServer лучший из лучших. А так запускать два сервера и в мыслях не было. Так вот хотелось оставить денвер на всякий случай и начать пользоваться с OpenServer.

PS. Благодарю всех за помощь и особенно **strangeqargo** за развернутый ответ, хоть что-то начал понимать про порты

Comment: Поставить - поставите. Вопрос только, а зачем? Перед установкой второй программы (например, опенсервера) не забудьте остановить первую (денвер), чтобы не были заняты порты.

Comment: Содержать на одном компе и денвер и опен сервер можно. Только использоваться одновременно нельзя. Включенным должно быть только что-то одно......Но лучше удалите денвер - это старая неподдерживаемая никому не нужная фигня

Answer (score 1):

denver и OpenServer  это не "две разные программы" это W **A** **M** P-стэк - набор программ в котором **A** означает веб-сервер Apache, а **M** - СУБД MySql.

и Апач и MySql могут привязываться к паре ip-адрес:порт - (допустим - 127.0.0.1:80 и, по дефолту для MySql - 127.0.0.1:3306). Сочетание адрес/порт должно быть уникальным для каждого процесса. Только один процесс может занимать *полный адрес* 127.0.0.1:80 единовременно. Иначе бы процессы не знали - какому именно процессу пришло сообщение.

Поэтому - если вы зачем-то хотите запустить два процесса веб-сервера и два процесса БД - они должны находиться на разных парах порт/адрес. Т.е. вам придется удостовериться в конфигах OpenServer/Apache и Denver/Apache (и, соответственно MySql), что они привязываются к уникальным айпи-адресам.

Другое дело, я подозреваю, что вы вовсе не хотите  развернуть несколько веб-серверов, а хотите развернуть несколько сайтов.

Для этого вам достаточно одного процесса веб-сервера (OpenServer или Denver - не важно) погуглите "Apache настройка virtual host", в случае с бд - может быть посложнее. Если ваши программы не затрагивают соседние базы, а работают только со своей базой - вам не нужен лишний MySql-процесс,  а вот если они свободно создают кучи баз данных, они могут перестать работать из-за конфликтов по наименованию баз данных или случайно удалить текущие базы. Такие системы встречаются редко, но вполне возможны (как пример - Phabricator)